# UK Visa Application For Family From Nigeria

Tags: visas, uk

I want to know the process to follow if I want to apply for a 6 month UK visa for myself, wife and children. Do I have to fill separate forms for each person and do I have to pay separately for each person including children under 8 years old?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58303/for-a-uk-visa-do-we-need-to-write-a-separate-covering-letter-or-shall-we-includ

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68892/accommodation-cost-in-uk-visa-application

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/75997/rules-for-being-a-dependent-on-a-uk-visa

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69117/uk-visitors-visa-for-my-son-2-years-and-i

Comment: @GayotFow meticulous use of the new feature :)